# If Take Five is in E-Flat Minor does that mean I use the G-Flat Major Scale as the basic structure for Take Five?

Tags: theory

I'm working on playing Take Five in E-Flat minor and "decoded" that E-Flat Minor is the Natural Minor for the key of G-Flat Major - and I wrote out the notes for G-Flat Major and they appear to fit with what I know of Take Five - is this CORRECT? Thanks for any help and explanations.

Comment: THANK YOU very much for this IN-DEPTH answer! It's better than taking a class! This is a wonderful forum - Best regards !! Gerry K in Kearny, Arizona

Answer (score 11):

You are correct in your assumptions but here is a slight adjustment in your terminology: Eb minor (natural minor) is the relative minor of Gb major. They share the same exact notes. However they do not share the same tonal center so it is better to conceive of the song as being in Eb minor and use Eb as your tonal center.

The melody to the A section of Take 5 is based on what is called the “minor blues scale”, a minor pentatonic scale with an extra chromatic note added between the P4 and P5 notes (Eb Gb Ab A Bb Db). If your purpose for learning this information is to know what to do when improvising over the A section, which is Ebm-Bbm, there are many options to choose from. One obvious choice is to play the Eb natural minor scale. Another is to play the Eb minor blues scale. A third option is to play Eb Dorian, another minor scale but with a M6 instead of an m6. Jazz players often will play Dorian over minor progressions because of its brighter sound and Eb Dorian does not clash with either chord. There are other options but these are a great starting point.

As for the B section, it is more “changes” based but largely in the key of the relative major, Gb. The bridge section is not improvised over on the original recording but many people do so in live performances. If you are still not adept at playing over individual chord changes playing in Gb major is pretty safe over that section.

Comment: Beat me to it ! +1. Might be worth noting that just like pent scales, there are 2 blues scales - minor blues and major blues. Working in the same way that pents do. So Eb minor blues uses the same notes as Gb major blues, so there's another option for the mid section. Although following the chords themselves works very well.

Comment: @Tim I’m not a fan of the term blues scale in general. I feel it trivializes and narrows the scope of what can be done and is done in blues music, but I rarely if ever see references to a major blues scale, even though I do hear it played often enough. I will edit my answer to include that though, thanks. By “major blues scale” I assume you mean the relative major of the blues scale built on the minor pentatonic scale, right?

Comment: Yes, the relatives. The tutti part of Sir Duke uses major blues notes - it can't really be said that it uses 'relative minor blues notes'! But, as I keep saying - all 12 notes are up for grabs in any key. Despite so many people here believing all notes should be diatonic.

Comment: @Tim …and here all this time I thought the riff in “Sir Duke” was an Ab minor blues scale! (Kidding of course) Great example of the “major blues scale” down to every single note.

Comment: Maybe your turntable is running a tad slow? It's in Cb major, isn't it? Making Ab blues spot on... (Also kidding - just).

Answer (score 4):

This gets at the difference between a scale and a key. I feel like sometimes people focus on which "scale" a song is "in," meaning a collection of notes to draw from. In this sense, yes, a natural minor scale and its relative major scale share the same collection of notes.

So what's the difference? Why not just say that "Take Five" is in Gb Major? The point of a *key* is that it's more than a collection of notes, it's how those notes relate to each other and where they center themselves. (You could parse all 8 church modes out of the notes of, say, a C major scale, with the only difference being where they "start.") "Take Five" is in a minor key not because of the notes it uses but because of how it uses them.

So short answer: Yes, you're correct in noticing that a natural minor and its relative major scale share the same set of notes.

Comment: Hi Andy, first I did not DV your answer which I think is unfair because it has useful information that does answer the question. I do take exception to your comment: “…in jazz circles, people focus on which "scale" a song is "in,"…”. I and all accomplished jazz musicians consider songs in keys, not scales and we use an analysis technique similar to traditional western music which identifies keys, modulations, secondary dominants, etc. Where the scales come in is for the purpose of improvisation, what to play over a given chord or chord progression but that is secondary to the key a song is in.

Comment: For jazzers, I believe it's more '*what set of notes (e.g.scale) works over this chord'*, which is maybe what you really meant. We're all very aware of what key a piece is in, as that's an important start point for any improv. - and yes, that inevitably gives us a set of notes (scale if you like) as a basis. However, all that said, I also believe that a lot of jazz players consider that *all 12 notes* are up for grabs - in any given key. I know I do!

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Fair enough; maybe my perception is more about "middle school jazz band." Edited to avoid throwing any stones!

Comment: I’ll give you “middle school jazz band (lol)  and a +1. I especially liked your second paragraph, excellent insights.

Comment: 8 modes out of 7 notes? How does that work?

Comment: THANK YOU very much for this IN-DEPTH answer! It's better than taking a class! This is a wonderful forum - Best regards !! Gerry K in Kearny, Arizona

Comment: @Tim How indeed? —ok, after [looking it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_mode), the only difference between Dorian and Hypomixolydian is the "final." Which I guess happens because you just get four of them from a tetrachord, and then the "hypo-" versions from shifting the finals of those...